# Saving webpage content using webbrowser IHTMLDocument interface

Tags: internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, mshtml

We need to save the complete web page including img, javascript, css and html using ATL webbrowser (IHTMLDocument) control,

using IHTMLDocument2::get_all() method we have saved .html file but now how do we get external files such as .css, javascript and image files
please help us with methods that internet explorer or firefox used to save the web page locally.

Thanks,
Ramanand.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be a rather manual task:

You can get a grip on the stylesheets by using the `IHTMLDocument2::styleSheets` property. The collection contains `IHTMLStyleSheet` elements, which in turn have a `href`-property which you can use to download the file. Scripts you can get via `IHTMLDocument2::scripts` which gives you a collection containing `IHTMLScript` elements, which have a `src` property. Same goes for images: use the `src` property to obtain a path. Somebody seems to do the same thing as you, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946111/retrieve-base-url-path-to-be-used-in-download-image-css-and-javascript-files-fro). There are also some hints about handling relative pathes.